# determine observations not included by filtering with dplyr - R

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, dplyr

When using `dplyr` on large dataframes, I often use multiple filtering arguments.   Often I could include these all in one `filter` argument.  However, I like the way dplyr allows you to think gradually about what you're doing with data, so often these filters may be on successive lines.

However, often I want to not only keep the observations produced by these successive filters in a new df, but also the observations from the original df that were not included in a separate df.

For example this dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
colors<- c( rep("yellow", 5), rep("blue", 5), rep("green", 5) )
shapes<- c("circle", "star", "oblong")
numbers<-sample(1:15,replace=T)
group<-sample(LETTERS, 15, replace=T)
mydf<-data.frame(colors,shapes,numbers,group)
mydf


   colors shapes numbers group
1  yellow circle       5     X
2  yellow   star      12     G
3  yellow oblong       7     B
4  yellow circle      14     I
5  yellow   star      15     Y
6    blue oblong       1     X
7    blue circle       8     S
8    blue   star      14     Q
9    blue oblong       9     Z
10   blue circle       7     R
11  green   star      15     S
12  green oblong       7     O
13  green circle      11     P
14  green   star       9     H
15  green oblong       2     D
```

Here, let's say I wanted to filter by the following rules (I'm aware that it may make more sense to filter in a different order, e.g. by color first, but for the sake of argument):

```
mydf %>% 
  filter (numbers <= 5 | numbers >= 12) %>% 
  filter (group=="X" | group =="Y" | group == "Z") %>% 
  filter (colors=="yellow")
```

which returns:

```
  colors shapes numbers group
1 yellow circle       5     X
2 yellow   star      15     Y
```

My question, is how could I keep the 13 observations from the original 'mydf' not returned by the filter into a separate df?  Is there a cute dplyr way?

Comment: `sepDf <- setdiff(mydf, mydf.filtered)`?

Comment: maybe `anti_join` could be useful?

Comment: @lukeA  - both of these solutions work well.  I think setdiff is slightly better as it maintains row order. - can you post as an Answer so I can tick it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest

```
sepDf <- setdiff(mydf, mydf.filtered)
```